# How to bind html in string using Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to find the solution for bind html in string example my string inside:

> Hello this is text `<a href="#">Kristoff</a>`  this is my domain
>   `www.website.com`

**Currently used:** `ng-bind-html="text | linky:'_blank' |` 
but I wanted result like this

`<a href="#">Kristoff</a>` to **Kristoff**  that bind href and `www.website.com` already bind by Angularjs

http://www.website.com/

What I want only bind `href` only.

Comment: read about [`$sce.trustAsHtml`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

Comment: Just rewrite you'r question. Its completely unreadable. What is is the output you get? and what is the output you want? You get `<a href="#">Kristoff</a>`? ...

Comment: ng-sanitize can be used.

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FfT6s/620/)

**JS :**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngSanitize']);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.htmlString = 'Hello this is text <a href="#">Kristoff</a> ' +
     'this is my domain <a href="http://www.website.com/">www.website.com</a>';

}]);
```

**HTML :**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <p ng-bind-html="htmlString"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: if I added <h1>Hello me</h1 it still bind to normal I don't want to bind any html just only href for security reason.

Comment: Then you have to `split` your string and apply the `ng-bind` only on `<a>` element.